# SQL, multiple sorting order

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask if i can achieve a query with one "order by" without using union:

```
first_order = column1 != column2;
seconder_order = column1 = column2;
third_order = column is null;
```

ex.     `select * from table_A order by first_order , seconder_order , third_order`

But when i try this its not working.

What im trying to do is to display on my table with this list first_order then second_order and last  the third_order. Im no expert on sql. Hope you can help me on this.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Explain what's not working.  You can definitely sort by multiple columns.

Comment: my example above returns the list with third_oreder thats column2 is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, try :

```
ORDER BY (CASE
    WHEN column1 != column2 THEN 0
    WHEN column1  = column2 THEN 1
    WHEN column is null     THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END) ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But im trying to use your query but im getting an error .
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE) ASC LIMIT 0, 1000'

Comment: @edmund: I believe the correct syntax uses `CASE … END` rather than `CASE … END CASE`.

Comment: YES! @ jonathan your also correct! After searching how to use CASE in mysql i finally run this query without error and achieved what im trying to do. I just remove CASE on END CASE. Thank you so much turutosiya! This is amazing!

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler I've just correct the statement.